Unexpected FlashList Jump on Screen Rotation in React Native/EXPO
PROBLEM: I'm experiencing an issue with the FlashList component in my React Native/EXPO app. When the screen orientation changes to album, the list unexpectedly "jumps" top over the visible part of the screen.
I have 3 columns with photos - in both orientations mode. Each column take all free space, so

in portrait mode: more content with smaller items size,
in album mode: less content but more item size.
For example I have images from 30 to 1, after rotating to album mode I expect that at least one row from portrait mode will be in album mode, but instead I have a line that was previously outside the visible area, (it keep the same places between multiple rotates, but for the album it is one place, for portrait another place). - you can see it on screenshots portrait mode
album mode

import React, {
  useCallback,
  forwardRef,
} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, useWindowDimensions, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Asset } from 'expo-media-library';
import { FlashList } from '@shopify/flash-list';
import MediaGridItem from '../MediaGridItem/MediaGridItem';

interface MediaGridProps {
  media: Asset[];
  onMediaPress: (index: number) => void;
  fetchMoreMedia: () => void;
  isFetchingMore: boolean;
  hasNextPage: boolean;
}

const MediaGrid = forwardRef<MediaGridHandle, MediaGridProps>(
  ({ media, onMediaPress, fetchMoreMedia, isFetchingMore, hasNextPage }, ref) => {
    const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
    const numColumns = 3;
    const itemSize = width / numColumns;

    const renderItem = useCallback(
      ({ item, index }: { item: Asset; index: number }) => (
        <MediaGridItem
          item={item}
          index={index}
          onMediaPress={onMediaPress}
          numColumns={numColumns}
        />
      ),
      [onMediaPress, numColumns]
    );

    const keyExtractor = useCallback((item: Asset) => item.id, []);

    return (
      <FlashList
        data={media}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        estimatedItemSize={itemSize}
        numColumns={numColumns}
        onEndReached={() => {
          if (!isFetchingMore && hasNextPage) {
            fetchMoreMedia();
          }
        }}
        onEndReachedThreshold={1}
        ListFooterComponent={
          isFetchingMore ? (
            <View style={styles.footer}>
              <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
            </View>
          ) : null
        }
      />
    );
  }
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footer: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
  },
});

export default MediaGrid;

WHAT I TRY: I understand that the problem is most likely related to changing the size of renderItem (flex: 1) and possibly estimatedItemSize.

I've tried tracking the index of the first element in a row that crosses the middle of the screen (no problem with that part), and then using scrollToIndex after changing the orientation (this also works unexpectedly - scroll to a "random" place).
I also tried to use ref instead of index for first item in middle row and use scrollToItem - but that didn't work either (scroll to a "random" place).

Has anyone else encountered this issue, or are there any known workarounds to keep the list position stable across orientations in FlashList?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
